# how would I best add client side validation to these two fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When user selects "Your Baptist Health experience". How would I best apply client side validation for "Name and Contact Information" input fields?

```
<ul class="textinput reason gridA">
  <li><p class="feedback"><label><input runat="server" type="radio" name="feedbackreason[]" aria-label="What would you like to tell us about?" aria-valuetext="Your Baptist Health experience" title="What would you like to tell us about?: Your Baptist Health experience" id="bhexperience"  class="feedbackreason reqType" value="bd" clientidmode="Static" /> Your Baptist Health experience</label></p></li>
  <li class="block panel-content marginT20">
      <div class="hidePanel" style="display:none">
      <p class="hl4">To enable us to respond to your comments, would you please let us know who to contact?</p>
      <p class="marginT10 marginL10"><label for="feedbackName" class="alignL">Name:</label><input type="text" name="feedbackName" id="feedbackName" class="text feedbackName marginL5" title="feedback Name" /><br />
      <br />
      <label for="contactInfo" class="alignL">Contact Information:</label><input type="text" name="contactInfo" id="contactInfo" class="text contactInfo marginL5" title="Contact Information" /></p>
      <p class="hl4 marginT10">For immediate patient portal service, please call
      <br />
      <strong><a class="phoneCall" style="color: mediumvioletred" href="tel:18446220622">1.844.622.0622</a></strong> (toll-free, 24/7)</p>       
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are just trying to require the user inputs a name.  What are you trying to validate?

Comment: I have set up this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zfjy3r2u/#&togetherjs=EHz01Pzt2r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added **required** to the input elements you want to force the user to fill out.

```
<ul class="textinput reason gridA">
  <li>
    <p class="feedback">
      <label>
        <input runat="server" type="radio" name="feedbackreason[]" aria-label="What would you like to tell us about?" aria-valuetext="Your Baptist Health experience" title="What would you like to tell us about?: Your Baptist Health experience" id="bhexperience"
        class="feedbackreason reqType" value="bd" clientidmode="Static" /> Your Baptist Health experience</label>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="block panel-content marginT20">
    <div class="hidePanel" style="">
      <p class="hl4">To enable us to respond to your comments, would you please let us know who to contact?</p>
      <p class="marginT10 marginL10">
        <label for="feedbackName" class="alignL">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="feedbackName" id="feedbackName" class="text feedbackName marginL5" title="feedback Name" required>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="contactInfo" class="alignL">Contact Information:</label>
        <input type="text" name="contactInfo" id="contactInfo" class="text contactInfo marginL5" title="Contact Information" required>
      </p>
      <p class="hl4 marginT10">For immediate patient portal service, please call
        <br />
        <strong><a class="phoneCall" style="color: mediumvioletred" href="tel:18446220622">1.844.622.0622</a></strong> (toll-free, 24/7)</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```